# Replace text inside a HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page template which uses PHP to pull data from an external website and it uses HTML to render the page layout.

Some of the data being pulled can't be changed at the source. So I need to change it on the actual website, as it's rendered.

The data I need changed is essentially a "status". And is coded as follows:

```
<span id="property-status"><?php echo $property['status']; ?></span>
```

There are three types of status coming from the source, and they are:

SOLD, CLOSED, and ACTIVE

I need to change SOLD and CLOSED to FUNDED.

The question is how do I achieve this using jQuery when the developers can't change it on their end.

Comment: `$('#property-status').text('your value here')`

Answer (score 1):

If is a string .Try with regex `/\>(.*?)\</gmi` and `String.replace()` function

```js
var obj ={'sold':'found','closed':'found'};

var a ='<span id="property-status">CLOSED</span>';

var res = a.replace(/\>(.*?)\</gmi,((a,b)=> '>'+obj[b.toLowerCase()]+'<'));
console.log(res)
```

Or with html use  `trim()` remove unwanted space

```js
var obj ={'sold':'found','closed':'found'};
 $('#property-status').text(obj[$('#property-status').text().trim().toLowerCase()])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="property-status">sold </span>
```

Comment: I've implemented the html version but for some reason it's only changing the word "closed" but not the word "sold".

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: paste your rendered  tag of span.without php

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it on client-side by comparing the element's text like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Your element 
  var status = $("#property-status");
  // It's text without spaces and to uppercase, for the comparison
  var status_text = status.text().trim().toUpperCase();

  if (status_text == "SOLD" || status_text == "CLOSED") {
    status.text("FUNDED");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="property-status">Sold</span>
```

---

**But!**... You also could do it on server-side, with a PHP function:

```
<?php
function fixStatus($status){

  // Text without space and to uppercase
  $status_to_compare = trim(strtoupper(status));

  if($status_to_compare=="CLOSED" || $status_to_compare=="SOLD"){
    return "FUNDED";
  }else{
    return $status;
  }
}
?>

<span id="property-status"><?php echo fixStatus($property['status']); ?></span>
```

[**PHPFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5enm-7j6j)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The jquery version is working and changes "Closed" to "Funded". However, It's not having any effect on the "Sold" status.

Comment: Do you mean that you actually tried it in your page? If yes... Tell me if it is `SOLD`, or `Sold` or maybe with a space.. like `SOLD ` ? -- Have you tried the PHP solution?

Comment: Hi, yes i've implemented the jquery version on the website. The actual word is Sold. And there's no space. I've not tried the PHP version.

Comment: Ok... I added the `.trim()` function to make sure there is no space and `.toUpperCase()` to compare the words. So event if there is some "variants" in the database, the comparison will work.